# Сіно збирають, громадять чи грабають?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, дієслова

Натрапила на різних сайтах на такі речення:

1. [Як вітаються в селі?](http://bereziv.kosiv.org.ua/2009/06/01/43/):

> Так не можна казати тільки в неділю, бо тоді люди не повинні робити та інколи можна побачити, як **сіно громадять**, бо буде дощ і щоб не намокло.

2. Пісня [Сінокоси](https://www.wikispiv.com/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8):

> А в вівторок рано
>
> **Грабав** тато **сіно**.

3. [Сонник: тлумачення і значення снів](http://morfei.com.ua/sino-do-chogo-snitsya-sino/)

> Скиртувати, **збирати сіно** час зайнятися своїм матеріальним становищем.

У [CУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghromadyty) знайшла усі ці 3 слова, однак яке слово найбільш точно відображає процес заготівлі сіна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Громадити** і **грабати** найточніше відображають процес заготівлі сіна. Оскільки цей процес здійснюється за допомогою граблів, тому, на мою думку, слово [збирати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zbyraty) краще підходить для означення «складати що-небудь докупи» (але з однинним іменником).

Також, на мою думку, чудово підходить для цього контексту [згрібати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zghribaty).